# Having the same member function have different definitions for different class instances

Tags: c++, function, class

Is it possible for the same member function to have different definitions for different objects of that class?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I cannot use a callback like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491538/can-the-same-function-be-defined-differently-for-different-objects-of-the-same-c). (reason explained below example)

Lets say we have this object:

```
struct object
{
    int n;
    int m;
    void f();
};
```

Is it possible to have something like:

```
object a,b;
// and here to define the functions
a.f() {std::cout << n+m;}
b.f() {std::cout << n-m;}
```

**The reason i cannot use a callback** is because the function i want to define will be recursive and will overflow. What i am trying to do with this method is to create an immitation of the stack (but all the variables are stored on heap as a double chained list) and so i will call a `void (void)` function that has no local variables thus increasing the stack depth the function can achieve. Also important to mention is that i want to make a header file with this idea. For further context explination, this is how it should work:

**MyHeader.h**

```
template <typename PARAM_TYPE> class HEAP_FUNCTION
{
private:
    struct THIS_CALL // ! THIS HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THE __thiscall CALLING CONVENTION !
    {
        PARAM_TYPE* PARAM;
        THIS_CALL* next_call;
        THIS_CALL* prev_call;
    };
    THIS_CALL* FIRST_CALL;
    THIS_CALL* CURRENT_CALL;

public:
    HEAP_FUNCTION(PARAM_TYPE* FirstCall)
    {
        FIRST_CALL = new THIS_CALL;
        CURRENT_CALL = FIRST_CALL;
        FIRST_CALL->PARAM = *FirstCall;
    }
    HEAP_FUNCTION(PARAM_TYPE FirstCall)
    {
        FIRST_CALL = new THIS_CALL;
        CURRENT_CALL = FIRST_CALL;
        FIRST_CALL->PARAM = FirstCall;
    }
    ~HEAP_FUNCTION()
    {
        delete FIRST_CALL;
    }
    void call(void);
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
// This is the ilustration of the recursive method for calculating
//  the 1+2+3+...+n sum.
// The "normal" definition for this function would be:
//
// unsigned long long sum(unsigned long long n)
// {
//     if (n == 0) return 0;
//     return n + sum(n-1);
// }
// 
// The function presented bellow is the equivalent.
struct Param
{
    unsigned long long n;
    unsigned long long return_value;
}
int main()
{
    Param start_value;
    start_value.n = 10; // we will calculate 1+2+...+10
    HEAP_FUNCTION<Param> Gauss(&start_value);

    // We imagine this is where i define call().
    // The code written in this definiton works correctly.
    Gauss.call()
    {
        // Test if the function needs to stop further calls.
        if(CURRENT_CALL->PARAM->n == 0)
        {
            CURRENT_CALL->PARAM->return_value = 0;
            return;
        }

        // Prepare the parameters for the next function call.
        CURRENT_CALL->next_call = new THIS_CALL;
        CURRENT_cALL->next_call->PARAM = new PARAM_TYPE;
        CURRENT_CALL->next_call->prev_call = CURRENT_CALL;
        CURRENT_CALL->next_call->PARAM->n = CURRENT_CALL->PARAM->n - 1;

        // Call the next instance of the function.
        CURRENT_CALL = CURRENT_CALL->next_call;
        call();
        CURRENT_CALL = CURRENT_CALL->prev_call;

        // Collect the return value of the callee.
        CURRENT_CALL->PARAM->return_value = CURRENT_CALL->PARAM->n + CURRENT_CALL->next_call->PARAM->return_value;

        // Delete the space used by the callee.
        delete CURRENT_CALL->next_call;
    }

    // This is the actual call of the function.
    Gauss.call();

    // The return value is found in the start_value struct.
    std::cout << start_value.return_value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Derivering the entire class will result in a single `call()` definition for funtions like `sum(a, b)` and `dif(a, b)` since they will use the same `PARAM` struct. (Even though they are not recursive, and the probability of someone using this is very small, this method is good in a bigger program when some of your functions will have a lot of parameters and just placing them on the heap will result in more stack space)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think I understood the question properly, but did you consider function overloading?

Comment: The reason function overloading won't do the thing is because firstly the user should not modify the header and secondly because you cannot overflow a `void (void)` function since the compiler would not make a difference.